# Spring MVC Restful App: Redirect a form result to another page

Tags: forms, spring, model-view-controller, rest, redirect

I'm new to Spring MVC Restful.
Suppose I have index.jsp which forwards user to a form page where user could submit a term to search. I catch the term with a POST handler method, and then do some calculation and hope to redirect the result to be used at another page (/WEB-INF/jsp), for example, we say build a graph based on the result. The problem is how to gather the results and redirect the URL at the same time.
The Controllers like below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/termForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView  setupForm() {
Term termClass = new Term();
return new ModelAndView("term", "command", termClass);
}
@RequestMapping(value="/getTerm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String getTerms(@ModelAttribute("term") Term term, BindingResult result)
{
    String label = term.getTerm();

    //doing some calculation to term here
    result = ....
    return "redirect:"+ "graphPage.jsp";
}
```

By searching, I found that Spring View Resolver only could process the redirected jsp under root directory (as same with index.jsp). In this case, the "result" seems not accepted by "graphPage". I also included UrlBasedViewResolver in XXX-servlet.xml as following:

```
   <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Sorry for the long question, please give any hint to do this. Thanks a lot.

---

There are two parts of my question. One is redirecting POST method to another page, graphPage.jsp. Since we go to graph, we need the data from POST method as well to create graph. This is the other concern. Hope it's clear. I already solved the first one by adding a handler method, see below. But how to package the result and pass it to Graph.jsp? Thanks

```
@RequestMapping(value="/graphPage", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showGraph()
{

    return "graphPage";
}
```

Comment: Solved. Use model.addAttribute("graph", result) to pass the reslut. And don't need redirect any more but return a String "graphPage". Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You will get a better controll over the redirect if you use the `RedirectView` instead of the String. See this example.

```
@Contoller
@RequestMapping("/your")
public class YourController


    @RequestMapping(value="/getTerm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getTerms(@ModelAttribute("term") Term term, BindingResult result) {
        ...
        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/your/other", true));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/other", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String otherMethod() {...}       
}
```

*But maybe you asked something different, then please rewrite your question. It is very hard to understand what your problem is.*/

BTW. test that you can request your "graphPage" directly

Comment: Thanks Ralph for your answer. Please see the updated question.